# Tool for mapping data from one Kafka topic to another with a different schema

Tags: apache, mapping

I want to read JSON messages from a Kafka topic with a certain schema. Then I want to transform/map this data to another format with a completely different schema. After this transformation I want to write the transformed data to another topic:

[image: Requirements]

Some of these mappings are simple attribute to attribute mappings. Some are a little more complex though.

I've already found out that you can do this with Kafka Streams and ksqldb. But the more complex mappings take a lot of manual effort. That's why I'm looking for a tool to reduce this effort.

Back when XML was still a thing I used Altova MapForce for tasks like this. But I can't find a suitable tool for mappings in a Kafka ecosystem. An on-premise solution would be perfect, but a cloud solution is also ok, if there's no other way.